# How to split string in r by first appearance of some character

Tags: r, regex, substring, strsplit

My data look like this:

```
106s(1m46s)
0s
15s
60s(1m)
```

I want to receive only the seconds:

```
106 
0
15
60
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want:

```
s <- c("106s(1m46s)", "0s", "15s", "60s(1m)")
as.numeric(sub("\\D.*$", "", s))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(str1, "\\d+"))
#[1] 106   0  15  60
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("106s(1m46s)", "0s", "15s", "60s(1m)")
```